# Where do I edit a MachineAd in HTCondor?

Tags: condor

I've been researching this question all day and neither the HTCondor docs nor Google could help me:

Where do I edit the MachineAd of a node in a HTCondor cluster? The `/etc/condor` folder on the node and on the master/schedd server do not contain any files that look remotely like a MachineAd.

I mean there is `condor_update_machine_ad` (https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/man-pages/condor_update_machine_ad.html) but that only sets the new value until `condor_startd` or the node are next restarted. There HAS to be a way to set an attribute persistently, right? ...right?

Thanks in advance for any help!